# rails console does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, console

I'm using rails Version 3.0.3 and ruby Version 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-15) on Windows Vista. Script console gives me the following error:

Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:2116:in `block in   _rl_read_init_file': invalid byte sequence in UTF
8 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:2114:in`each_line'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:2114:in `_rl_read_init_file'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:2080:in`rl_read_init_file'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:2500:in `readline_initialize_everything'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:3726:in`rl_initialize'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:4720:in `readline'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/readline.rb:40:in`readline'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/input-method.rb:115:in `gets'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:139:in`block (2 levels) in eval_input'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:138:in`block in eval_input'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:188:in `call'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:188:in`buf_input'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:103:in `getc'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/slex.rb:205:in`match_io'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/slex.rb:75:in `match'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:286:in`token'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:262:in `lex'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233:in`block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in`block in each_top_level_statement'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in`each_top_level_statement'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in`block in start'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in`start'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in`start'
        from C:/privat/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in`require'
        from script/rails:6:in `'

What can I do?

Comment: What do you have in 'script/rails'?

Comment: Did you try executing `rails console`? That is how to launch the console in Rails3 (i.e. you no longer use `script` commands).

Comment: Yes the command I used is "rails console".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Ruby1.9.2 has some issues with encoding... You have to check if your db driver is not giving error.. Does your server run? I recommend you to use Ruby187

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I spent hours trying to fix it, rebuilding ruby, etc... For any setting of LANG= it was failing.

Finally I discovered in the code that it was during the load of the init file, that is, ~/.inputrc.

My $HOME in the problematic computer had not the ~/.inputrc... I tried to create an empty one and... worked!

So try `touch ~/.inputrc`

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this same issue with rails 4.1.1, and it turned out that my `~/.inputrc` file was encoded using the ISO-8859-1 encoding. After converting the file to UTF-8, everything worked fine:

```
$ iconv --from-code=ISO-8859-1 --to-code=UTF-8 ~/.inputrc >out
$ mv out ~/.inputrc
```

To check what encoding your `inputrc` file is encoded with, use:

```
$ file --mime-encoding ~/.inputrc
```